# How does Zipify One Click Upsell works? What is high level architecture?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-javascript-buy-sdk

Can anyone explain the high level architecture and API's involved that Zipify have used to make One Click Upsell tool ? Do they have some special API access from shopify to make post purchase one click transactions. Have they used js buy sdk ?

Comment: Um... shouldn't this be a question directed at the app developer, not a StackExchange forum?

Comment: I have tried there but no answers so far

Comment: Then they're probably protective of their code, which is entirely reasonable for a business. I mean, if somebody you don't know was asking you for the keys to duplicate code that you wrote to make an income for yourself, what would you do? Rather than asking to reverse-engineer somebody else's code, which feels sketchy at best, I would strongly recommend changing your question to be about what YOU want to do and the specific problem that you're trying to solve.